# Error sending request from Azure Function

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-functions

I have an **Azure Function** that I have configured that listens for incoming messages to an **Azure Service Bus**. I can receive the messages without a problem. But when I try to route the request onto another service for processing, I am getting an error stating that the POST data is empty.

```
public static void Run(BrokeredMessage message, TraceWriter log)
{
  log.Info($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {message.MessageId}");

  if (message != null)
  {
    //MessageObjectEntity is a custom object
    Common.Entities.MessageObjectEntity messageObject = message?.GetBody<Common.Entities.MessageObjectEntity>();
    string msgType = messageObject?.MessageType;
    var msgContent = messageObject?.MessageContent; // MessageContent is of type object to allow any object to be sent

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        string url = $"http://mycompany.azurewebsites.net/api/routingtasks?formname={msgType}";
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(subscriber, token);
        HttpContent content = new StringContent((string)msgContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = client.PostAsync(new Uri(url), content); // at this point content is valid

        // I am getting a BadRequest returned here as the target service has not received the POST data
        // that was sent in via the content variable
    }

    log.Info("Completing message.");
}
```

It appears that the POST data sent in the variable *content* is not received despite it being sent.

**UPDATE**

When I inspect the JSON sent to my Azure Function in the logger it looks like this.

```
{"FormName":"UpdateMileage","FormData":[{"Key":"enteredmileage","Value":100},{"Key":"todaysdate","Value":"01/01/2017"}],"Profile":{"EmailAddress":"unittest@mycompany.co.uk","ID":9999999}}
```

Which doesn't work.

But if I hard code the following JSON from my Azure Function it works correctly (the double quotes are needed to escape the back-slashes).

```
"\"{\\\"FormName\\\":\\\"UpdateMileage\\\","\\\"FormData\\\":"[{\\\"Key\\\":\\\"enteredmileage\\\",\\\"Value\\\":100},"{\\\"Key\\\":\\\"todaysdate\\\",\\\"Value\\\":\\\"01/01/2017\\\"}],"\\\"Profile\\\":"{\\\"EmailAddress\\\":\\\"unittest@mycompany.co.uk\\\","\\\"ID\\\":9999999}}\""
```

The problem therefore appears to be the formatting of the JSON that is being sent from my Azure Function, but I don't how I would convert my JSON into this format.

Comment: If you POST to something like http://requestb.in do you see the contents of `content`?

Comment: I haven't heard of this utility before but it looks useful. I'll give it a go and see what results I get.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the fact that I was sending JSON to my ASP.NET Web API service, but sending it as a string type. This is wrong.

The following [article](http://bizcoder.com/posting-raw-json-to-web-api) explains the correct approach when sending JSON data as a POST request.